# using web-kit gradient and image in CSS background

Tags: css, webkit

I'm attempting to place an image on top of this class as well as keeping the current background added using Web-Kit Gradiant

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, 
color-stop(0.03, #3A79C1), color-stop(0.99, #5F9EE6), 
color-stop(1, #75ABEA)) url(images/bg.gif) no-repeat center right;
```

Although it's adding the background just not the image, is the code right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right idea, however you're missing a comma and also you want your image to show on top of the gradient.. Not below! So re-arrange the order. Check out this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sDRuc/)

```
background: url('images/bg.gif') no-repeat center right,-webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, 
color-stop(0.03, #3A79C1), color-stop(0.99, #5F9EE6), 
color-stop(1, #75ABEA)) ;
```